# WCF Service Context.Response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to conver a ASMX webservice to a WCF webservice, the problem is it keeps saying Context doesn't exist in the current context.
Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PhBookService
{

    [OperationContract]
    public void GetAllCities()
    {
        List<Cities> listCity = new List<Cities>();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BS-HP-PC-11\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PhoneBookData; Integrated Security=true; User ID=phonebook;Password=phone");
        using (connection)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from d_City", connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Cities City = new Cities();
                City.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CityID"]);
                City.CityN = reader["CityN"].ToString();
                listCity.Add(City);
            }
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer javascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(javascript.Serialize(listCity)); -- this line here is where I get the error.
    }

}
```

Adding any type of using System."something" doesn't seem to work for me. What should I do?

P.S. This is my ajax request.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you included all your code, but a WCF service typically includes several things such as an interface that represents your contract. In your case, you should just return a list of cities.

That being said, I would structure your code a bit differently:

- [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx) for your city type
- Interface that represents your ServiceContract which includes the
  OperationContract
- A class that implements the ServiceContract (interface)

  ```
  [DataContract]
  public class Cities
  {   
      [DataMember]
      public string CityN {get;set;}

      [DataMember]
      public int CityID {get;set;}
  }

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface ICities
  {
     [OperationContract]
     List<Cities> GetAllCities();
  }

  public class PhBookService : ICities
  {
      public List<Cities> GetAllCities()
      {
          List<Cities> listCity = new List<Cities>();

          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BS-HP-PC-11\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PhoneBookData; Integrated Security=true; User ID=phonebook;Password=phone");
          using (connection)
          {
              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from d_City", connection);
              connection.Open();
              SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  Cities City = new Cities();
                  City.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CityID"]);
                  City.CityN = reader["CityN"].ToString();
                  listCity.Add(City);
              }
          }

          return listCity;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a DataContract, I have a class with get;set; though. I'll update that. Will this make my url: different when using ajax?

Comment: No it should not. The DataContract is a formal agreement between a service and a client that abstractly describes the data to be exchanged. It should make things clearer if you use one.

Comment: I'm getting and error implementing this :
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collentions.Generic.List<Cities>' to 'System.Collentions.Generic.List<City>'"

Comment: Its just a naming thing. In my sample, I called the class City. But in yours, you called it Cities. My code was just an example of a pattern that you should use plus mention that you were not returning Cities. I edited my answer to use your naming convention of "Cities". Though I do think your datacontract should be be called City.